# Методы range и len

Tags: python

Сразу сообщу, я только начал изучать Python. Пока изучил темы : Переменные, Условные операторы, Функции, Циклы (for, while, break,range),списки,кортежи.Но вернулся снова к спискам,не всё понял, так как темы  взаимосвязаны и по сложнее.Понимаю, что пока мои познания по этим темам поверхностны.

Не могу понять.

```
x = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]

for i in range (len(x)):
    x[i] += 3
print(x)
```

Получится:
[12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6]

Process finished with exit code 0

Я понимаю что записью for i in range (len(x)):    - с помощью этого  цикла  мы итерируем весь список х.  Но всё равно, не совсем понятно . Что при этом происходит, по буквам, операциям , что происходит в этой записи -   range (len(x)):   ?  В переменную i что в итоге передается , сами индексы или значения под этими индексами . После запуска кода , понимаешь что переменной i присваиваются значения х . Но как то мало примеров с такими сочетаниями и не совсем понятно.  В предыдущих уроках не нашел примеров  сочетания range с Len . По сути эта запись range (len(x)),  указывает (range) диапазон по всей длине (len) переменной х. Я понял так, не знаю правильно или нет ...

Но если написать так :

```
x = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]

for i in range (len(x)):
    i += 3
print(i)
```

Получится:
9

Process finished with exit code 0

Почему то не прибавилось 3 ко всем значениям в i  ...... Короче, я запутался. :)

И соответственно не понятно объяснение следующего кода  (пример как воспользоваться  значениями  из  кортежа,  с переносом этих значений в переменную ( y),для того чтобы потом  изменить эти данные, делать какие нибудь операции с ними. Точнее  сама запись  y.append(x[ i ] + 3) , что именно в этой записи происходит, почему   i    в квадратных скобках [ ]...... ?  Я понимаю , что мы в переменную (y)  добавляем значения из кортежа .... Не понятно только добавляем из (х),  или из (i) ......?  То есть не понятно сочетание x[i] .

```
x = (9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3)
y = [ ]
for i in range (len(x)):
    y.append (x [ i ] + 3)
print (x)
print (y)
```

Может я не понял из-за того что плохо усвоил  про функцию len ....... Но вроде из предыдущих тем "Циклы" , с примерами вопросов не возникало.
Примеры:

```
x = ""

while len (x) < 5:
    y = input ("Ввод данных: ")

    x += y

else:
    print(x)
```

Получится :

Ввод данных: h
Ввод данных: e
Ввод данных: l
Ввод данных: l
Ввод данных: o

hello

Единственное,  что в этом примере простое и понятное сочетание len (x) - ограничение длины в 5 символов .  А вот с таким сочетанием  как  range (len(x)) со ссылкой на какую-нибудь переменную, примеров видимо не встречал пока, может это меня и столку сбило .......

Ткните носом, что я не правильно понял ....
Фу, хотел вкратце спросить , но получилось как получилось. :)

Comment: `В переменную i что в итоге передается , сами индексы или значения под этими индексами` ну добавьте в цикл `print(i)` и посмотрите что там оказывается (еще лучше - запустите в режиме отладки и выполните пошагово). `После запуска кода , понимаешь что переменной i присваиваются значения х` - интересно, с чего вы это решили.

Comment: i-index, x[i] - элемент списка с индексом i

Comment: len длина списка
range(N) это диапазон от 0 до N-1, т.е индексы списка
т.е вот этот цикл

for i in range(len(x)):

он перебирает только индексы, а к самим элементам надо обращаться
через x[i]. Ну и менять i внутри списка совсем нелогично, непонятно что там вообще будет, но так делать нет смысла. i и так по всем элементам range проходит, изменять i в цикле безсмысленно.

Comment: немного дополню @insolor, внутрь цикла добавьте print(f’{i=} {x[i]=}’) и смотрите, что печатается, анализируйте

Answer (score 1):

`x[i]` - i-ый элемент в x (нумерация начинается с 0)
Функция range генерирует последовательность чисел. У неё есть три параметра: начало - begin, конец - end и шаг - step. Если условно вызвать `range(1, 7, 2)`, то мы получим последовательность `[1, 3, 5]` - последовательность, начинающийся с 1, каждый следующий на два больше, все значения < 7. Иногда некоторые значения можно пропускать. Например, `range(10) = range(0, 10, 1) = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, или `range(2, 7) = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] = range(2, 7, 1)`.
Каждый раз, когда мы пишем

```
for i in range(len(a))
```

в переменную i передаются последовательно числа от 0 до len(a), не включая последний. i используется как индекс списка.

В первом фрагменте кода вы просто пробегаетесь с помощью i от 0 до `len(x)` и прибавляете к каждому элементу 3.
Во втором фрагменте происходит следующее. На каждой итерации цикла i присваивается новое значение из последовательности и к нему прибавляется 3, т.е. сначала `i = 0`, потом вы увеличиваете i на 3, она становится 3, но на следующей итерации 3 затирается единицой - следующим числом в последовательности. На последней итерации i присваивается 6, к i прибавляете 3, получается 9.

Comment: range не создает список. оно там может хранится как угодно, но по типу это не список, легко проверить если вывести type(range(5)) is list и type([]) is list. False в первом и True во втором случае.

Comment: 1) Вы не ответили на все вопросы автора. Например, "что я неправильно понимаю?" Расширьте ответ, пожалуйста. 2) Выделите, как принято, части кода (`код` - левая верхняя клавиша). Пояснение: этот мой комментарий - в рамках стандартной проверки "первых сообщений".

Comment: Согласен, ошибся.

Answer (score 0):

все очень просто. range генерирует диапазон чисел. len возвращает длину последовательности. далее узнаем новое слово "протокол итератора". цикл for..in в пайтон единственный (в JS их 3 вида, кажется) и всегда делает одно и то же, он итерирует итератор поэлементно.

Например, возьмем последовательность букв (чтобы отличать элементы от индексов)

```py
arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
# теперь мы хотим добавить к каждому элементу еще букву. Так как int и str 
# неизменяемые типы данных то сделать вот так не получится
first_element = arr[0]
first_element = "ab"
print(a[0])  # 'a'
```

ах да, квадратные скобки на последовательность это обращение к по индексу. в данном случае я прошу нулевой индекс у последовательности arr.

Однако, так как мы используем тип дпнный list, наша последовательность является изменяемой последовательностью. Не все последовательности изменяемы tuple  и не все последовательности поддерживают индексацию set.

```py
arr[0] = "ab"
print(arr[0])  # 'ab'
```

Идем далее. Так как мы не можем менять строки, то для того чтобы изменить каждый элемент списка, нужно узнать его длину и сгенерировать другой список, который будет содержать номера индексов.

```
indexes_arr = list(range(len(arr)))
```

теперь у нас 2 списка. И мы можем сделать так.

```
arr[indexes_arr[0]] = "ac"
print(arr[0])  # 'ac'
```

Что я сделал? Я взял нулевой элемент списка indexes_arr и изменил элемент под этим номеров в списке arr. Теперь мы можем итерироваться по indexes_arr.

```
for arr_i in indexes_arr:
    arr[arr_i] = arr[arr_i] + "c"
print(arr)  # ['ac', 'bc', ...]
```

И закрепим

```
for i in arr:
    print(i)
```

Тут главное понять, чтобы вы не делали с i в данном случае это никак не отразится на arr, и НЕ потому что это свойство for..in, а потому что тип str immutable. А вот если бы элементы списка arr были бы изменяемы, то отразилось.

```
arr = [[0], [1], [2]]
for i in arr:
    i[0] += 1
print(arr)  # [[1], [2], [3]]
```

И еще кое что я скажу явно.

```
x = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
range(len(x))  #  тут вы создаете генератор, который выдаст вам числа 
# в диапазоне от нуля до len(x) невключительно.
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо. Повторюсь,я новичок.Только начал изучать. В теме отредактировал,добавил в начале описание.
Прочитал все ответы, голова пока переваривает всю информацию :).
Есть вопросы к каждому кто здесь ответил. Сейчас пока всё осмыслю, попробую правильно формулировать дальше вопросы .... . Но зато пока понял, что я не до конца понимал  понятия индексы и элементы которые находятся под этими индексами.
То есть процитирую **"цикл for i in range(len(x)): он перебирает только индексы,  а к самим элементам надо обращаться через x[i].** Хоть стало более менее понятней для чего именно используются к примеру : **for i in range(len(x)):  и  x[i]** .
Так же стало не много понятнее, после прочения  разбора на примере:  **arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"] .....**
Но все равно в каждом ответе, в комментарии кое что спрошу....